# Regex to match every things separated by a space

Tags: java, regex

Basically I would like to capture everything separated by a space or new line.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried?  There's probably ways to do it without RegEx.  (I don't know much of the stdlib, but most languages have a `split` or `explode` function.)

Comment: I trying to decipher why this `[^\\w']` gives me more words that what is below

Comment: @Ben: The difference between `[^\\w']` and `[ \n]` is that the former matches many more characters, including hyphens, commas, periods, and so on. It bears mention that `split` does not remove empty strings from the output, except at the end of the input, so something like `"Yes, no."` would become `["Yes", "", "no"]` using your pattern (where comma is a splitter), vs. `["Yes,", "no."]` using mine (where comma is not a splitter). If you don't want commas (etc.) in your output, but also don't want empty strings, try `[^\\w']+`, with a plus sign.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you just want

```
String[] output = input.split("[ \n]");
```

?